# Getting the ellipse function to match the dataEllipse function in R

Tags: r, ellipse

So I am sampling from a multivariate normal distribution in R, and am trying to figure out how to calculate its 95% confidence ellipse using the ellipse() function in the package car.

Here is some code I am running:

```
mu = c(0,0)
sigma = matrix(c(20,0,0,45),nrow=2)

z = rmvnorm(10000,mu,sqrt(sigma))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(z)
ellipse(mu,sqrt(sigma*qchisq(.05,2)),radius=1)
dataEllipse(z,levels=.95)
```

So basically I want the ellipse command to replicate the dataEllipse command.  If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:  Using Dwins code and combining it within my own:

```
library(car)
library(mvtnorm)

mu = c(0,0)
sigma = matrix(c(20,0,0,45),nrow=2)

z = rmvnorm(10000,mu,sqrt(sigma))

dataEllipse(z,levels=.95)
car::ellipse(mu, sigma*qchisq(.05,2), col="blue", 
                 radius=sqrt(2 * qf(.975, 2, 9998)) )
```

[image]

So as you can see, the ellipses are still not the same...

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing (although you should not have made me do so) that `rmvnorm` is from 'mixtools' and it was loaded after 'car'. I do not think the sqrt() function is needed since the argument to `ellipse` is supposed to be a covariance matrix. Also at the moment it is plotting but you cannot see it, because you didn't color it red (or anything). Furthermore both 'mixtools' and 'car' have `ellipse` functions, so if you want the car-version ( which does have a radius argument unlike the mixtools version) then you need to call it with the double colon convention:

```
library(car); library(mixtools)
car::ellipse(mu, sigma*qchisq(.05,2), col="red", 
                 radius=sqrt(2 * qf(.975, 2, 9998)) )
```

Comment: rmvnorm is actually from the library(mvtnorm).  And yes, I did not mean to attach the sqrt() function to my covaraince matrix.

Comment: However, if you run that code you provided, you still do not get the same answer as the dataEllipse() function.

Comment: What is the justification for your choice of parameters?  I am having a hard time in general figuring out how to correctly use the radius parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Since this post is still getting views, I'll provide the actual answer. The last three lines of this code snippet replicates `car::dataEllipse` exactly:

```
library(car)
library(mvtnorm)

mu = c(0,0)
sigma = matrix(c(20,0,0,45),nrow=2)
z = rmvnorm(10000,mu,sigma)

dataEllipse(z,levels=.95)

center <- apply(z, 2, mean)
cov_mat <- cov(z)
ellipse(center, cov_mat, col="red", radius=sqrt(2 * qf(.95, 2, 9999)))
```

Note that both `car::dataEllipse` and `car::ellipse` return the coordinates of the points silently, so one can confirm that the points are indeed equal.